# Button not responding when inside UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIPageViewController` with `UIPageControl` at the bottom like so:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50, 
width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX-30, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 30, width: 20, height: 20))
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: rect)
self.view.addSubview(button)
self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
```

But whenever I put the button inside the bounds of the `UIPageControl` view the button doesn't respond to my clicks, but when I move it outside of it it works fine and triggers the action. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Okay so the issue was the order of adding subviews, I needed to add pageControl first and then the button

Comment: It's due to the z-index, whenever you add a subview it goes on top of the others contained in the parent view.